# What color would be produced by the burning of the listed chemicals of the projectile weapon the carcass?

Tags: combustion, color

The carcass was a projectile weapon developed by the French in the second half of the 17th Century. It was "named [carcass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcass_(projectile)) because the circles which pass from one ring, or plate, to the other, were thought to resemble the ribs of a human carcass."

[image]
illustration from the article "[The British Fire Bombing of Quebec City in 1759](https://www.militaryheritage.com/fire_bombing_quebec_1759.htm)"

The internal [chemical constituents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcass_(projectile)#Composition) are described as

"10 parts of pounded gunpowder, 2 of nitre (potassium nitrate, KNO₃), 1 of sulfur, and 1 of colophony (rosin)"

OR

"6 of gunpowder, 4 of nitre, 4 of sulfur, 1 of beaten glass, 0.5 of antimony 0.5 of camphor, 1 of sal armoniac, and 0.25 of common salt"

and the exterior was covered in

"4 parts of melted pitch, 20 of rosin, 1 of oil of turpentine, and as much ground gunpowder as was needed to reduce it to the consistency of a paste. After immersion, the shell was to be covered with tow, and immersed again"

Is there any way to determine or estimate what color the exterior would burn during flight, or what would be the color when the interior ignited? What color would be the smoke either during the flight or during the burning of the interior?

Comment: The smoke is usually made of soot (impure charcoal), which is black. And when it burns, soot produces a yellow color

Comment: But the flames *might* be coloured by the potassium in the nitre and gunpowder.